# Is there a way to have an adaptable prepared statement for an sql query

Tags: php, mysql

So i am trying to create a HTML front end that can use a text field to search an SQL Database. But there are multiple columns that can be searched, and many columns that contain numbers or letters. The User can search one or many of the columns at a time.

In my own test server, I've tried breaking down the possible queries into dropdown lists; and have switch cases to handle the selections. But this hasn't worked. My ultimate goal would be to have the textbox host all the query data, and have it passed to a prepared statement

So my question; is there a way to make a prepared statement adaptable, to handle single search cases or multiple search case. eg. WHERE column1 LIKE query1 (AND column2 LIKE query2).

Comment: Don’t let users send bits of SQL you would concatenate into your query. But you can definitely build your query on demand based on user parameters, as long as you make sure that column names come from your list, NOT user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic concept, obviously you need to do your own validation and sanitizing etc. In your html use an array to hold all the form values:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Col1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="database[column1]"><br>
  Col2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="database[column2]"><br>
  Col3:<br>
  <input type="text" name="database[column3]"><br>
```

Then process that array to prepare a query

```
$input = $_POST['database']; // Assign all form variables to $input
$input = array_filter($input, 'strlen');  //  Remove any form fields which were submitted with empty values
$where = implode(' AND ', (array_map(function($a){return "'$a' LIKE ?";}, array_keys($input)))); // Assemble your list of WHERE clauses
$statement = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $where");
$statement->execute(array_values($input));  // Execute statement with corresponding variables
```

You can use this database query to get a list of columns for your table. Then using `array_intersect_key` you could filter out and column names which were submitted but did not exist in the table

`SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='table';`

Answer (score 0):

This maybe long-winded and I am sure there are better approaches where you could loop it out or array. *Col1 text box must have data for this to work due to the "AND", I hope this helps.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Col1:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Col1"><br>
  Col2:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Col2"><br>
  Col3:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Col3"><br>
  Col4:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Col4"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"><br>
</form>

<br />
<br />

<?php


$SQL_Claus = "";

if (!empty($_POST['Col1'])){
    $Col1 = $_POST['Col1'];
    $SQL_Claus = $SQL_Claus . " Col1 LIKE " . $Col1;
}
if (!empty($_POST['Col2'])){
    $Col2 = $_POST['Col2'];
    $SQL_Claus = $SQL_Claus . " AND Col2 LIKE " . $Col2;
}
if (!empty($_POST['Col3'])){
    $Col3 = $_POST['Col3'];
    $SQL_Claus = $SQL_Claus . " AND Col3 LIKE " . $Col3;
}
if (!empty($_POST['Col4'])){
    $Col4 = $_POST['Col4'];
    $SQL_Claus = $SQL_Claus . " AND Col4 LIKE " . $Col4;    
}

$SQL_Statement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ".$SQL_Claus;
echo $SQL_Statement;

?>
```

Comment: PS. No security measures in place and may need JS for text field Col1.